# How to run node.js and angular2+ at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, package.json

I have node.js project with Angular4CLI in folder "UI"

node.js package.json:

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
...
```

and Angular package.json:

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
...
```

How to start node.js and angular at the same time?

I've tried wrong solutions:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js && ng serve",
    "start-2": "node index.js && cd .\ui\ && ng serve",
}
```

Please help. 
thanks advance

Comment: try `"start-2": "node index.js && cd ui && npm start"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into angular universal.

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

The documentation makes usage clear, and there a few decent seed repositories out there too.

Look for qdoubles material pre-rendering webpack-starter, it is really straight forward to merge an existing application into this starter too.